# Parse unicode digits in Go

Tags: go, unicode

Other answers mention using [`unicode.IsDigit()`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#IsDigit) to check if a given rune is a digit or not, but how do I figure out *which* digit it is then?

Atoi and ParseInt from [`strconv`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv) won't parse it.

IsDigit checks a table with all of [these codepoints](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) in it, but I can't figure out anything from that. Many of the number ranges start with their 0 digit at a codepoint ending in 0, but not all of them so I can't just `char & 0xF`.

My only other thoughts is whether there's a way to either access the unicode name of a rune, or whether you can access properties. Every numeric unicode character (even fractions) seems to have a plain ASCII number associated with it [behind the scenes](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) as a property, but I can't seem to find a way to access either that information or the name (all unicode digits have names ending in "DIGIT ZERO" for example) anywhere. Am I looking/building outside of the standard library on this one?

Comment: You already have the rune... What other information are you interested in?

Comment: @jub0bs its numeric value. I'm asking how I figure out that this  is an integer 3.

Comment: The "numeric value" might not be well defined. E.g.  Mayan number go up to 12. Some languages might not have a code point for 4.

Comment: @Volker The documentation of `IsDigit` states that only decimal digits return true, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [runenames](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames) package to identify a digit based on the name.

This isn't a stardard library package, but it is part of [golang.org/x/](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x)

> These packages are part of the Go Project but outside the main Go tree. They are developed under looser compatibility requirements than the Go core. Install them with "go get".

```golang
import (
    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/runenames"

    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func whatDigit(digit rune) int {
    var name = runenames.Name(digit)
    switch {
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT ZERO"):
        return 0
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT ONE"):
        return 1
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT TWO"):
        return 2
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT THREE"):
        return 3
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT FOUR"):
        return 4
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT FIVE"):
        return 5
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT SIX"):
        return 6
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT SEVEN"):
        return 7
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT EIGHT"):
        return 8
    case strings.Contains(name, "DIGIT NINE"):
        return 9
    default:
        return -1
    }

    return 0
}
```

The package does mention a document https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt which seems to have further information for each character, including specifying which digit the character is in plain ASCII, however, this package only provides the name. Just looking through the document, the names seem to follow the pattern as shown in the `whatDigit` function.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the package and the data I was looking for. Thanks for the help!